# Is there any possible way to remove the very bottom, top, left and right side lines?

Tags: html, css

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdzz73/25/
Where I have the code placed: http://testblogty678.blogspot.com/

Image: i.imgur.com/3tqGKf6.png

I want to know, is there any possible way to remove the very bottom, top, left and right side lines?

```
    <table align='center' height='100%'>
      <tr>
        <td valign='middle'>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 1
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 2
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 3
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 4
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 5
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="one">
    Radio 6
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="two">
    Radio 7
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="two">
    Radio 8
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
              <td class="two">
    Radio 9
                <br/>
                <span class="two">
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    ------------------------------

td {outline:1px solid blue;}

td.one{
    color: #EB7225;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-right: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 100px; 
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  span.two{
    color:#000000; 
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 24px;
    background-color:#E2AB58;
  }

  td.two{
   color: #F984E4;
   line-height:1;
   font-size:30px;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding-top: 0px; 
   padding-right: 50px; 
   padding-bottom: 0px; 
   padding-left: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually added that yourself! So just don't!

Consider this modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/ok3gzxzh/

CSS: `td table tr td {outline: 1px solid blue;}`

With your original example you added an outline to *each* table cell, so also the cell of the *outer* table holding *all* the inner table. That was the outer line you saw. So if you modify your css rule defining the outline such that it only applies to the cells of the *inner* table you get the desired result.

Comment: Which of these codes do you like better?

td td {
outline: 1px solid blue;
}

or

td table tr td {outline: 1px solid blue;}

Comment: That is a question of personal preference, there is no right or wrong. `td td` _should_ be sufficient, the longer version is more robust against a faulty html structure and easier to understand in my eyes.

Comment: When you do 25px line height, it adds a double line, how do you get rid of that? Look: https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdzz73/33/

Answer (score 1):

use outline like this

```
td td {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Outline will apply inner inner table columns only.

Comment: Which of these codes do you like better?

td td {
outline: 1px solid blue;
}

or

td table tr td {outline: 1px solid blue;}

Comment: Both will give same result, but it is short in length so I thought it is better.

Comment: When you do 25px line height, it adds a double line, how do you get rid of that? Look: https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdzz73/33/

Answer (score 0):

You applied an outline to the td element.
The middle element gets also a border. Just remove it.

Html:

```
<td valign="middle" id="noborder">
```

Css:

```
#noborder{outline:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this. Adding `border-collapse: collapse` to the table will remove the extra line. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdzz73/27/)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
td.one {
  color: #EB7225;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
span.two {
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #E2AB58;
}
td.two {
  color: #F984E4;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table align='center' height='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td valign='middle'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 1
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 2
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 3
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 4
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 5
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="one">
            Radio 6
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="two">
            Radio 7
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="two">
            Radio 8
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="two">
            Radio 9
            <br/>
            <span class="two">
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just you need to update the td role in your css as the following

```
td {border: none;}
```

and add this new role after the above one

```
td > table td {outline:1px solid blue;}
```

Comment: When you do 25px line height, it adds a double line, how do you get rid of that? Look: https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdzz73/33/